# Small validation accuracy ResNet 50

Tags: deep-learning, keras

https://github.com/slavaglaps/ResNet_cifar10/blob/master/resnet.ipynb

This is my model trained in 100 epochs
Accuracy on similar models and similar data reaches 90%
What is my problem?
I think it's worth reducing the learning rate with the passage of the epochs.
What do you think that can help me?

Comment: " similar models and similar data reaches 90% " - please give sources / be more specific here

Comment: Are you sure the others don't use ensembles / test time augmentation?

Comment: `x_train = x_train/255` - what is the `dtype` of `x_train`? Int or float? (Please check it; don't guess - you could also visualize it with `scipy.misc.imshow` to make sure data is correctly loaded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few subtle differences.

1. You are trying to apply ImageNet style architecture to Cifar-10. First convolution is `3 x 3`, not `7 x 7`. There is no max-pooling layer. The image is downsampled purely by using stride-2 convolutions.
2. You should probably do mean-centering by keeping `featurewise_center = True` in `ImageDataGenerator`.
3. Do not use very high number of filters such as [512, 1024, 2048]. There are only 50,000 images for you to train unlike ImageNet which has about a million.

In short, read up section 4.2 in the [deep residual network paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) and try to replicate the network. You may also read [this](http://florianmuellerklein.github.io/wRN_vs_pRN/) blog.